# Details about which user from csv failed response assertion in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter to webUI performance testing. I have a list of users in csv with passwords. I am using response assertion to check failed password scenario.

How to record which user from csv is failed?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going for [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property. For example, if you defined a `${username}` which holds the user name from the CSV you can get it added to JMeter .jtl results file by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
sample_variables=username
```

If you need to store more variables - provide them separated by commas:

```
sample_variables=username,password
```

Remember that:

- JMeter restart is required to pick the property up
- You can pass it via -J command line argument as well like:

  ```
  jmeter -Jsample_variables=username,password -n -t test.jmx -l results.jtl
  ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on different JMeter properties types and ways of working with them